# Delay in receiving messages via MSMQ 5.0 intermittently

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, msmq, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an client server application which makes use of MSMQ for communication. The server runs on Windows Server 2008 R2 and client workstation works on Windows 7 OS. MSMQ version is 5.0.

Intermittently there is a huge delay of around 20-40 sec. between the time the message is sent and the time when message is received.

I have found out a similar problem in google for MSMQ 3.0
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909401

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2010/01/23/troubleshooting-message-queue-messages-get-delayed-intermittently.aspx

But could not find anything similar to MSMQ 5.0

Can any one help me on this ?

Thanks in advance...!!!